# I am new to salesforce and performing this query getting error

Tags: soql

```
SELECT Name, Account.Id, Contact.Email 
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE Amount > 500 AND Contact.Email != ''
```

Please explain me where I am wrong.

Comment: This query is malformed , the Contact object is not directly related to the Opportunity object, and therefore cannot be queried in this way. The correct relationship would be through the Account object using a subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct query could be:

```
SELECT Name, Account.Id, (SELECT Email FROM Contacts) FROM Opportunity WHERE Amount > 500 AND AccountId != null
```

This query selects the name and account ID of all opportunities with an amount greater than 500 and whose account ID is not null. It also includes a subquery to retrieve the email of all related contacts.

Also refer this discussion for your understanding -

> [Relationship between contact and opportunity](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000gEEkQAM)